# Can I communicate via an encrypted connection in United Arab Emirates?

Tags: legal, internet, uae

I use `git` quite frequently to upload code to a remote server while traveling. This software makes use of a secure shell (ssh) protocol to transmit data. Data transmitted in this manner is encrypted via 2048-bit RSA keys and could not be read by any authority monitoring my wifi connection.

Can I legally use such a service from a public wifi connection in the United Arab Emirates?

Comment: http://www.emirates247.com/business/technology/vpn-use-punishable-under-law-dubai-police-2015-03-12-1.583914 basically, it is only prohibited if the use is related to a crime.

Comment: I wish there were a comprehensive list of countries of these sort...

Answer (score 3):

The UAE is somewhat famous for banning VPNs -- but it's unclear whether that's only if you use them to commit illegal activities or whether even a company VPN is illegal which would be strange to say the least -- nonetheless, there is no ban on using encrypted communications to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: A healthy amount of web search on encryption ban united arab emirates only finds references to the old kerfuffle with Blackberry in 2010 and the VPN stuff. Given how easy it is to find material on the UAE VPN ban surely there'd be more on an encryption ban. Finding the source of a negative is hard?